# Issue with PHP code for searching correct values from MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a website where there is a search function. The search function can be found at [**bypadmin.ipage.com**](http://bypadmin.ipage.com). The search function works well but have a minor issue. When I select only **REGION** or only **COUNTRY** or only **DURATION** it shows correct search result. But when I select a County and a Duration or a Region and a Duration, it shows incorrect Result.

For example, when I search Country: Melbourne and Duration: 4 days in the search it shows the Tour BYP Melbourne where as it should actually show NO TOURS AVAILABLE as the tour is listed under 30 Days.

Similarly when I select a Region and a Duration, It sometimes shows tours which are not listed under that region but is under the particular duration. I want to search with AND function, but now the search result is showing with OR function.

Below is my PHP code:

```
                <?php
                 $rf=mysql_query("select * from homepage_place where id=1");
                $fetbtn=mysql_fetch_array($rf);?>
                <div id="left" style="background-color:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bdy_cl']); ?>">

                 <div id="left_top" style="background-color:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['heading']); ?>">
                 <font style="line-height:45px;"><?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['heading_text']); ?></font>
                 </div>


                 <form name="searchform" method="post" onSubmit="return Validate();">
                 <table width="80%" style="margin:auto;background:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bdy_cl']); ?>;
                 ">
                 <tr style="font-size:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bdy_fntsize']); ?>"><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                 <tr style="height:30px;">
                 <td height="39"><font style="font-size:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bdy_fntsize']); ?>;font-style:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bdy_text']); ?>;color:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bdy_text_cl']); ?>">Region</font></td>
                 <td>
                 <select name="region" id="region">
                 <?php echo $options; ?>
                                </select>
                 </td>

                 </tr>
                 <tr style="height:30px;">
                 <td height="41"><font style="font-size:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bdy_fntsize']); ?>;font-style:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bdy_text']); ?>;color:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bdy_text_cl']); ?>">Country</font></td>
                 <td>
                 <select name="country" id="country">
                 <option  value="any">All Country</option>
                 <?php
                if($_POST['region'] == "")
 {
    $res_country1 = mysql_query("select DISTINCT country_name from country");
 while($fet1 = mysql_fetch_array($res_country1)){
    $country_name1 = $fet1['country_name'];
    $country_id1 = $fet1['id'];

    echo "<option value='$country_name1'>$country_name1</option>";


 }

    }
                ?>


                 </select>



                 </td>

                 </tr>
                 <tr style="height:30px;">
                 <td height="42"><font style="font-size:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bdy_fntsize']); ?>;font-style:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bdy_text']); ?>;color:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bdy_text_cl']); ?>">Duration</font></td>
                 <td>
                 <select name="duration">
                 <option value="any">
       All Duration
     </option><?php
                $sql_duration=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT duration from duration");
                ?>


                 <?php
                 while($fetch_duration=mysql_fetch_array($sql_duration)){?>
                 <option><?php echo $fetch_duration['duration']; ?></option>
                 <?php } ?>



                 </select>

                 </td>


                 </tr>
                 <tr style="height:30px;">
                 <td height="39"><font style="font-size:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bdy_fntsize']); ?>;font-style:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bdy_text']); ?>;color:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bdy_text_cl']); ?>">Keywords</font></td>
                 <td><input style="height:30px;border: 4px solid #ddd;" type="text" name="key" placeholder="Place,activity or code." /></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr style="height:30px;">
                 <td height="48" colspan="3" align="center">
                 <button style="margin-left:28%;width:130px;height:30px;background-color:<?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['bellow']); ?>;" type="submit" name="submit">
                 <?php echo stripslashes($fetbtn['button_text']); ?></button>
                 </td>
                 </tr>
                 </table>
                 </form>


                 <?php
                if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
                {
                $region=$_POST["region"];
                $country=$_POST["country"];
                $duration=$_POST["duration"];
                $key=$_POST["key"];

                $search5=mysql_query("select * from tour WHERE region LIKE '%$region%' and duration LIKE '%$duration%'");
                $row5=mysql_num_rows($search5);
                if($row5>0)
                {
                    ?>
                     <script>
 window.location="tours_placewise5.php?region=<?php echo $region; ?>
  & country=<?php echo $country; ?> & duration=<?php echo $duration; ?>"</script>
                     <?php

                    }

                $search=mysql_query("select * from tour WHERE duration LIKE '%$duration%' and country LIKE '%$country%'");
                $row=mysql_num_rows($search);
                if($row>0)
                {
                    ?>
                     <script>
 window.location="tours_placewise.php?region=<?php echo $region; ?>
  & country=<?php echo $country; ?> & duration=<?php echo $duration; ?>"</script>
                     <?php

                    }



 $search1=mysql_query("select * from tour WHERE duration LIKE '%$duration%'");
 $row1=mysql_num_rows($search1);
                if($row1>0)
                {
                    ?>
                     <script>
 window.location="tours_placewise1.php?region=<?php echo $region; ?>
  & country=<?php echo $country; ?> & duration=<?php echo $duration; ?>"</script>
                     <?php

                    }
 $search2=mysql_query("select * from tour WHERE country LIKE '%$country%'");
 $row2=mysql_num_rows($search2);
                if($row2>0)
                {
                    ?>
                     <script>
 window.location="tours_placewise2.php?region=<?php echo $region; ?>
  & country=<?php echo $country; ?> & duration=<?php echo $duration; ?>"</script>
                     <?php

                    }
 $search3=mysql_query("select * from tour WHERE region LIKE '%$region%'");
 $row3=mysql_num_rows($search3);
                if($row3>0)
                {
                    ?>
                     <script>
 window.location="tours_placewise3.php?region=<?php echo $region; ?>
  & country=<?php echo $country; ?> & duration=<?php echo $duration; ?>"</script>
                     <?php

                    }
 $search4=mysql_query("select * from tour WHERE region LIKE '%$region%' and country LIKE '%$country%'");
 $row4=mysql_num_rows($search4);
                if($row4>0)
                {
                    ?>
                     <script>
 window.location="tours_placewise4.php?region=<?php echo $region; ?>
  & country=<?php echo $country; ?> & duration=<?php echo $duration; ?>"</script>
                     <?php

                    }


                    else if($region == any and $country == any and $duration == any)
                    {
                        ?>
                     <script>
                    window.location="tours.php";
                    </script>
                     <?php

                        }


                if($region != "" && $country != "" && $duration != "")
                    {
                        ?><center><span style="color:red;font-size:18px;">Sorry!!! Tours Not Found..</span></center><?php
                        }




                    }
                ?>
```

This is my [**database table**](http://s22.postimg.org/a260p9hv5/image.jpg)

Any other information required can be asked.

Comment: That code is just terrible, SQL queries all over the place and HTML/JS code mixed in … I’d suggest you go and structure that better first – by first checking your input data, then making the necessary queries, and finally output data in the end.

Answer (score 0):

All of your inputs are selects. So you don't need to use LIKE in your sql statements.

```
WHERE region LIKE '%$region%'
```

can just be

```
WHERE region = '$region'
```

As for your duration, i suggest instead of using a varchat type in your database, you should use an integer to show how many days or hours the tour is (you can also have another field that is varchar for output to the user). This will return you better results in your queries.